# Zakat Calculation: Fluctuating networth

Tags: zakat

I originally asked [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/313/calculating-zakat) which I am splitting up.

Fluctuating Net worth: Some months, one saves more and some months one spends more due to various reasons. How does one establish the correct "wealth" to pay zakat on? Since according to definition, it has to sit idle for 1 year before we pay zakat on it. The local imam I talked to suggested to take an average of the two net worths and pay zakat on that.

Comment: Is this about Zakat or Khums? AFAIK, zakat doesn't apply to the condition you described.

Comment: well basically Zakat is applicable on what you save. So if you save X dollars in a month, it gets added to the pool of money you are not using, hence zakat ought to be applicable. But I don't know, that is why I asked.

Comment: I disagree and it's not what I learned. and the answer makes perfect sense. Perhaps you misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my understanding, any money that you have had for more than one lunar year is considered *"wealth"* and zakaat has to be paid on wealth if your net worth crosses minimum nisaab.

So go through your bank statement of the lunar year and see what is the lowest balance on the statement.

Lets say you have $3000 as the lowest, this means that this $3000 was sitting as wealth in your account, so you should pay zakaat on it if you are eligible.

Also, remember if you pay more it will benefit you...so sometimes its better to be safe than sorry.

May Allah Guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you monthly salary does not fall under the category of zakat. In other word you do not need to pay Zakat on it because it is flowing money. It comes in and it goes away. You do not save most of it. Zakat is obligatory on 4 types of wealth

1. Animals that feed outside home
2. Gold or Silver
3. Goods that you use for business/trade
4. Agriculture and Treas

So for example you have 10 gm of Gold and keep it for 6 months, no Zakat is required on that Gold. The term 1 years basically means, you are wealthy enough to pay Zakat. It has not been made a burden on us.

Comment: Thanks. From what I know, it is on wealth you are not using hence anything you save.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hanafi madh'hab, as long as you have maintained the *nisab* for a full year, you will owe zakat on the entirety of your zakatable assets when it becomes due.

So, for example, if you start the year with $1,000 in your account (which is above the *nisab*) and end the year with $20,000, you would still pay zakat on the entire $20,000, even though you did not possess that entire amount for a complete year.

Comment: What is the minimum amount of money that one needs to have in account, in order to qualify for submitting zakat?

Answer (score 0):

For bank accounts you have to fix a day of the year(usually 1st of Ramadan but can be any day of the year) and pay zakat on it at the rate of 2.5%. If some money comes in the account a day before, it's zakat is due and if it goes a day before, it is exempted.

Usually banks set this to 1st Ramadan