# I received $4000 dollars, which exceeds nisab, but spent it on food and circumcision before one year of getting, it, do I have to pay zakat?

Tags: zakat

I work at Starbucks and I give all interest immediately to charity. I regularly take money out for food and the last bit of money I had, I used to get circumcised. I spent all the money before one year was completed after I exceeded nisab. Do I have to pay zakat?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Hanafi school, zakat is due on the total you have after the year has passed.  It doesn't matter if some of that money has not been [in your possession for a whole year](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/319/22), it only matters that you've maintained at least the *nisab* for the year.

If you have not maintained the *nisab* for a full year, no zakat is due.

Answer (score 0):

Zakat on savings is to be paid by fixing a day of a year. If, on that day, you have money above nisab, then you pay zakat on that. The day can be any day, as long as it is the same for every year.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the "the day can be any day".  Isn't it supposed to be the day you get paid for the very first time and/or the day you obtain/buy gold/silver for the first time.