# Zakkat, how to calculate it?

Tags: zakat, calculate

It there any tool can help me to calculate zakat by easiest way .. I need also some examples for how to calculate zakat to make it easy for me to calculate mine.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. All you need is basically available online https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat (wikipedia) an online calculator http://www.zakat.org/donate/zakat-calculator/ (in $) an other http://www.islamic-relief.org.uk/about-us/what-we-do/zakat/zakat-calculator/ (in £) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zakat Calculation: Fluctuating networth](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/319/zakat-calculation-fluctuating-networth)

Comment: What specifically do you require that isn't readily available by [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zakat+calculator%22)?

Answer (score -2):

I think there is a fresh post I read about zakat calculations and also there is a free file to download explaining by details and examples for how to calculate zakat .. but you should know that the file is in Arabic Language

Here is the thread URL:
https://hrdiscussion.com/hr103259.html